# How to create an empty html file in my shopify website?

Tags: shopify

is it possible to create an empty html file say ex : myname.html
I tried to create a layout and add it to a page, but it seems the layout cannot be empty.
I got an error while creating an empty layout file.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Sorry i cannot post this under "Shopify" tag under webmaster or meta version or stackexchange,
because there is no such tag in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's okay for the URL of the page to be /pages/myname and not /myname.html, then here's another work-around:

1. Go To Blogs & Pages and create a page. Call it, say, 'My Page'. Give it the handle 'myname'.
2. Go to Themes > Template Editor, and create a new 'page' template under Templates. Call it say, 'special'. The name of the file will become page.special.liquid.
3. Delete the content of that file. At the top of the file, add this: {% layout none %}, then add your HTML. Save.
4. Go back to your 'My Page' under Blogs & Pages, and assign your page.special template to it. Save.

See this for more info: http://support.shopify.com/customer/portal/articles/263930-creating-and-using-an-alternate-template-for-pages-products-collections-and-blogs

Comment: When done with the above, add an 'URL redirect' in your shop admin, under the Navigation tab. Make the source of the redirect  /myname.html and redirect to /pages/myname.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can’t do this in Shopify.

However, if you can deal with redirects, what you could do is make an empty html file under /admin/files/list and redirect to that.

Comment: Edward, i have only shopify admin panel, how do i access the folder /admin/files/list?

Comment: @balanv Just visit https://YOUR-SHOP.myshopify.com/admin/files/list    For example, if your store is http://iliketurtles.myshopify.com then visit https://iliketurtles.myshopify.com/admin/files/list

Answer (score 0):

There's a good visual explanation on how to do this with redirects a little way down this thread:
http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-marketing/t/verifying-website-on-pinterest-112464

(To verify for Pinterest for Business, but should work with others as well)

To sum up:
 1. Upload the verification file to account > Show uploaded files 
 2. Grab the URL
 3. Go to Navigation > URL Redirects 
 4. Add verification URL as 'old path' and actual position of file as 'new path'.
 5. Verify